# Node.js - Return nested function value

Tags: node.js, promise, node-schedule

I´m new in Node.js and just learn the basics in using Promises and async functions. Currently I´m struggling to achieve a return from a nested function using Promises. Although there are similar questions to (I think the same issue), I still don´t get it working. 
Here´s what I want to achieve.

With the function **jobScheduler** I create a new job using the **node-schedule** module which is retrieving data from a service between two dates (variables **start** and **end**) with an specific recurrence rule (variable **rule**). The service is returning data in form of true / false (which is working properly). And now I need to return this value of the service by the **jobScheduler** function with a promise. The job scheduler is working perfectly as it should, I´m just struggeling to return the true / false value by my jobScheduler function.

```
function jobScheduler(start, end, rule, cycle) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        schedule.scheduleJob({start: start, end: end, rule: rule}, async  function () {
            const data = await service.getData(cycle);
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Asynchronously derived values can't be returned. `jobScheduler()` is correctly written to return `Promise`; the Promise will *deliver* `true/false`. The calling function must be written to access the delivered value via `Promise.then(...)` or the equivalent `async/await` syntax. It's a common misunderstanding that asynchronously derived values should somehow be returned. I have voted to close with a reference to a comprehensively answered question.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing up. I´m calling this function inside a async one together with await. Merry christmas!